# Three.js position model with touchscreen?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking over the documentation for three.js right now and have found the controls section. I see that it's possible to use orbit to control the cameras view of the scene and I ahve confirmed that this works with touchscreen. What I cannot find anywhere online is if it has the possibility to rotate, scale, and transform a loaded model. I see that transform exists but I can't find anything else that I would need for it.

Comment: `OrbitControls` is for the camera only. If you want to add controls to manipulate a loaded model, then you'd have to write them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event listeners to the canvas by yourself and detect intersections. If intersection with the desired object was made, then  make transformations depending on the event to it.